# Build Docker image on AWS CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I'd like to build a Docker image on CodeBuild and then push it to ECR. I want to do this so I can have a clean build environment for my Docker images. What is the simplest way to do this?

I've tried using the official `docker:latest` image from Docker hub but it requires two containers to be running at the same time (the daemon and the client), which CodeBuild doesn't let me do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible by selecting the following option when creating your project:

[image]